# Java 11 Functional flow infers wrong type on method call

Tags: java, generics, types, functional-programming, java-11

I have this kind of code:

```
public interface Checker<A,B> extends BiFunction<CheckRequest<A>,Function<A,B>,CheckResponse<B>> { // ... }

public class CheckResponse<B> {
  private B operationResponse;

  //...

  public void setOperationResponse(B operationResponse) {
   this.operationResponse = operationResponse;
  }

  public B getOperationResponse() {
    return operationResponse;
  }
```

}

and a method like:

```
public B execute(A req){
  CheckRequest<A> chkReq = //...
  chkReq.setOriginalRequest(req);

  Function<A,B> op = //...

  CheckResponse<B> chkRes= checker.apply(chkReq ,op)
  // [...]
  return chkRes.getOperationResponse();
}
```

I want to wrap the execution of "op" into a checker object that will perform some other side effects. I also need to wrap the input and the output of "op" into proprer CheckRequest and CheckResponse to pass and get back additional data. But then, to get back the original result for "op", I need a getOperationResponse() method in CheckResponse. Sounds easy.

The above code is working as expected but, if I "inline" it like:

```
return checker.apply(chkReq ,op).getOperationResponse();
```

I got

> incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to [actual
>   type of B]

Why return type of getOperationResponse() is not correctly inferred if method calls are inline?

I'm using OpenJDK11 from Oracle:

> IMPLEMENTOR="Oracle Corporation" IMPLEMENTOR_VERSION="18.9"
>   JAVA_VERSION="11" JAVA_VERSION_DATE="2018-09-25"

Intellij IDEA 2018.3 and Maven 3.5.4 on Windows 10.

Comment: Could you provide the (relevant) code of the `CheckResponse` and `CheckRequest` classes? Also, could you add the code here: `CheckRequest<A> chkReq = //...` and here `Function<A,B> op = //...`. It sounds like you are using raw-types somewhere, causing the `checker.apply(chkReq, op)` to become of type `CheckResponse` (which is somewhat similar, but not exactly the same as `CheckResponse<Object>`) instead of `CheckResponse<B>`, causing the error given.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen you probalby right I missed a peache of code in which I use a factory class like:

`public Checker getChecker(OperationType operation) {
        switch(operation){
            case getOperation: return new SecurityChecker<GetOperationRequest, GetOperationResponse>(serviceRepository);
            default: throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unsopported Operation: "+operation);
        }
    }`

Which return type is to much "raw", if I understand correctly your hint..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure your `checker` is defined on the lines similar to:

```
Checker<A, B> checker = new Checker<A, B>() {
    @Override
    public CheckResponse<B> apply(CheckRequest<A> aCheckRequest, Function<A, B> abFunction) {
        // perform whatever operation and return a CheckResponse of type B
        return new CheckResponse<>();
    }
};
```

Few underlying assumed complete classes here are :

***Response model***:

```
class CheckResponse<B> {
    private B operationResponse;

    public void setOperationResponse(B operationResponse) {
        this.operationResponse = operationResponse;
    }

    public B getOperationResponse() {
        return operationResponse;
    }
}
```

***Request model***:

```
class CheckRequest<A> {
    private A operationRequest;

    public void setOperationRequest(A operationRequest) {
        this.operationRequest = operationRequest;
    }

    public A getOperationRequest() {
        return operationRequest;
    }
}
```

and then your complete definition of the method could be

```
public B execute(A req) {
    CheckRequest<A> chkReq = new CheckRequest<>();
    chkReq.setOperationRequest(req);

    Function<A, B> op;// intialised

    Checker<A, B> checker = new Checker<A, B>() {
        @Override
        public CheckResponse<B> apply(CheckRequest<A> aCheckRequest, Function<A, B> abFunction) {
            // perform whatever operation and return a CheckResponse of type B
            return new CheckResponse<>();
        }
    };

    return checker.apply(chkReq, op).getOperationResponse();
}
```

I can confirm the above works fine for me syntactically.

Comment: Is this a "must" to have anonymous inline `Checker` implementation? Why I cannot just a use an instance of a concrete class that implements `Cheker` interface?

Comment: @AleZ I accidentally deleted my previous comment, but no, it doesn't have to be inline. You can create a loose class which implements the `Checker` interface. Just make sure the class is something along the lines of `class CheckerImpl<A, B> implements Checker<A, B>` with the overwritten `apply`-method in _nullpointer_'s code. The important part is the diamond operator `<>`. Without it, the `new CheckerResponse();` would be 'raw' as I described in my comment underneath your question. You can then use `Checker<A, B> checker = new CheckerImpl<A, B>();`.

Comment: @AleZ No as Kevin points out as well, that was just to demonstrate the types bound with the interface and how the method `apply` could be called thereafter successfully.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks for the explanation, quite similar to what I intended to explain using the example.